# options -a and -s in UNIX if statement

Tags: shell, unix

I am working with some code where I am seeing a `-s` option used along with an `if` statement.

```
if [ ! -s ABC -a ! -s DEF ]
then 
    echo "yes"
fi
```

My doubt is what do `-s` and `-a` do generally in an `if` statement.

The actual code is:

```
if [ ! -s curHs.$mad.$mid -a ! -s prHs.$mad.$prid ]
```

Comment: Which shell is this?

Comment: First learn that the `[` in the condition is a command, and that it's an alias for `test`. Then read the [`test(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) manual page.

Comment: `man test` => `-a` : `AND`, `-s`: file exists and has a size greater then zero.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I am absolutely new to all this . Sorry if this turned out to be not such a great question.

Comment: Note that `-s` (lower case) and `-S` (upper case) have different meanings.  The first checks whether “FILE exists and has a size greater than zero” while the latter checks whether “FILE exists and is a socket”.  I have edited your question to use the lower case version consistently.  I see no reason why your question would be bad.  It's something quite elementary but that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

First learn that the `[` in the condition is a command, and that it's an alias for `test`. Then read the `test(1)` manual page.
                    – Some programmer dude

`man test` => `-a` : `AND`, `-s`: file exists and has a size greater then zero.
                    – Wrikken